# Can I assign a template directory to a Symfony controller?

Tags: php, templates, symfony

I store templates under `app/resources/views` [in accordance with the Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html#template-naming-and-locations), and under that views directory, I have a couple more layers of directories to keep my templates organized.

In most of my controllers, all of the actions render templates from the same subdirectory, for example, all of the actions in `MyController` use templates in `app/resources/views/foo/bar`:

```
class MyController extends Controller
{

    public function someAction()
    {
        // stuff
        return $this->render('foo/bar/some.html.twig');
    }

    public function otherAction($id)
    {
        // more stuff
        return $this->render('foo/bar/other.html.twig');  // same dir, different template
    }
}
```

Is there a "Symfony" way to assign that specific `foo/bar` directory to the controller just once so I don't have to keep repeating it?

I'm currently doing it by assigning the directory to a protected property and wrapping the parent render method to append it to the template name like this:

```
protected $view_path = 'foo/bar/';

protected function render($view, array $parameters = array(), Response $response = null) {
    return parent::render($this->view_path . $view, $parameters, $response);
}
```

So then I can just write `return $this->render('some.html.twig');` instead.

But I'm thinking there's probably already a cleaner built-in way that I haven't found in the docs yet, like an annotation on the class or something. Does anyone know of a better way?

Comment: what the point? why not to use this - [Referencing Templates in a Bundle syntax](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html#referencing-templates-in-a-bundle) ?

Comment: The point, to me, is to avoid typing the same thing repeatedly. And I've seen that part that you linked, but my templates aren't in a bundle. They're just in the default `app/resources/views` location.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I think your last solution is pretty clean already. It makes your intentions explicit.

Comment: @Pete Thanks! I'm _okay_ with it, I just don't want to reinvent the wheel; if the framework already offers something that does what I'm trying to do I'd rather use that.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Hmm.. What are you looking for then? Something like a `@TemplatePath` annotation that you can annotate the class with? I'm not sure whether I would prefer such an annotation over the solution you already use. But I am biased - I hate PHP "annotations" because they feel unnatural.

Comment: @Pete yeah, something along those lines. Some kind of configurable option, not necessarily an annotation, but something like that. (I have mixed feelings about them too, although I do use them, I know what you mean.)

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use [Namespaced Twig Paths](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/namespaced_paths.html). This should allow you to use shortcuts for your paths.

In your config.yml, set namespaced twig path like that :

```
twig:
    paths:
        '%kernel.root_dir%/../app/resources/views/my/very/long/path/foo/bar/': foobar
```

And in your controller :

```
public function someAction()
{
    // stuff
    return $this->render('@foobar/some.html.twig');
}
```

**EDIT**

If you really want to avoid to repeat path for every action then you can probably consider creating a controller listener (on kernel.controller event) with Twig_Loader_Filesystem as parameter.

In this listener, write something like this (I haven't tested this code) :

```
class pathListener
{
    private $loader;

    function __construct(\Twig_Loader_Filesystem $loader)
    {
        $this->loader = $loader;
    }

    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $controller = $event->getController()[0];

        if (isset($controller->view_path)) {
            $this->loader->addPath($controller->view_path);
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to add a path without overriding the render method to each controller.

Comment: This would help somewhat. In fact, the main reason that the repetition was bothering me is that my real path is actually quite a bit longer than `foo/bar`. But even if it was shorter, I'd still need to repeat it for every action, which is what I'm trying to avoid, ideally.

Answer (score 2):

There are annotations, that will set the output template, where you would simply return the array of data to potentially fill in that template (which could be an empty array).

To use it:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class AboutController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Template("About/index.html.twig")
     * use the template from /app/Resources/views/About/index.html.twig
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        return ['key' => 'data'];
    }
}
```

If there won't be any custom data being put into the template, you can also do it entirely within the routes:

```
app_about_hello: # just show the template for the URL path
    path:  /about/hello
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Template:template
        template: ':About:hello.html.twig'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I do know about the template annotations for the specific actions, but I'm trying to assign a directory to the class that defines a common directory where all the different templates for the various actions will be located. Based on your answer and the other comment, I think I need to edit my question to be more clear about what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I edited the question. Hopefully I was able to describe my goal a bit better.